# Why is numdifftools so inaccurate? How does it work?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using python's numdifftools library to perform derivatives. However, a few tests prove the library is highly inaccurate:

```
import numpy as np
from numdifftools import Derivative
# Result should be 1/2 or 0.5
Derivative(np.log, 1)(2.0)
>>> array(0.5493061443340549)
```

Is there a way to fix this inaccuracy?

Comment: which version of numdifftools are you using? I used 0.9.16. Then `Derivative(np.log, i=1)(2.0)` throws a syntax error, but `Derivative(np.log)(2.0)` gives the correct result (`array(0.5000000000000238)`)

Comment: Maybe also clarify your question: Do you want to know how numdifftools works or do you want to fix the inaccuracy.

Comment: @FabianRost My ultimate goal here is to fix the inaccuracy, but I suspect understanding how numdifftools work can get me to the root of the problem. I'm using numdifftools 0.9.14 from Anaconda

Comment: the code you posted throws an error with numdifftools 0.9.16. I don't think they changed the API that much. Could you please review and rerun your code? Maybe it's `Derivative(np.log, n=1)(2.0)` instead of `
Derivative(np.log, i=1)(2.0)`?

Comment: @FabianRost Ah yes, that i is a mistake. I just changed to 0.9.16, upgraded numpy, still got the same result!

Comment: which python and which numpy version are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue spotted.

```
Derivative(np.log, 1)(2.0)
```

gives the wrong answer. The n should be explicitly stated:

```
Derivative(np.log, n=1)(2.0)
>>> array(0.5000000000000234)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using numdifftools 0.9.16 and numpy 1.9.3 the following code gives an exact result:

```
import numpy as np
from numdifftools import Derivative
# Result should be 1/2 or 0.5
Derivative(np.log)(2.0)
```

Output:

```
array(0.5000000000000238)
```

Comment: I spotted the problem. When I use `Derivative(np.log, 1)(2)`, it returns the wrong answer. But when I specified `Derivative(np.log, n=1)(2)`, I got the right result.